# sklearn StackingClassifier and sample weights

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, xgboost

I have a stacking workflow which is similar to

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.ensemble import StackingClassifier
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
import xgboost as xgb

X = np.random.random(size=(1000, 5))
y = np.random.choice([0,1], 1000)
w = np.random.random(size=(1000,))

scaler = StandardScaler()
log_reg = LogisticRegression()

params = {
    'n_estimators': 10,
    'max_depth': 3,
    'learning_rate': 0.1
}

log_reg_pipe = make_pipeline(
    scaler,
    log_reg
)

stack_pipe = make_pipeline(
    StackingClassifier(
        estimators=[('lr', lr_stack_pipe)],
        final_estimator=xgb.XGBClassifier(**params),
        passthrough=True,
        cv=2
    )
)
```

I'd like to be able to pass sample weights into the xgboost. My question is **how do I set sample weights in the final estimator?**

I have tried

`stack_pipe.fit(X, y, sample_weights=w)` which throws

```
ValueError: Pipeline.fit does not accept the sample_weights parameter. You can pass parameters to specific steps of your pipeline using the stepname__parameter format, e.g. `Pipeline.fit(X, y, logisticregression__sample_weight=sample_weight)`
```

Comment: The error message is pretty straightforward, isn't it?  And why do you have a pipeline surrounding the single step `StackingClassifier`?

Comment: This is a minimal reproducible example from an actual problem; I had the pipeline surrounding it because the real problem has some preprocessing. Obvs I've tried to access final_esimator__sample_weight, but it doesn't work.

Comment: The problem is that `StackingClassifier` doesn't let you pass fit parameters to the base learners. `StackingClassifier.fit` only has a `sample_weights` parameter, but it then passes those weights to _every_ base learner, which is not what you've asked for.  Anyway, that also breaks, with the error you reported, because your base learner is actually a pipeline, and pipelines don't take `sample_weights` directly. If you want all the base learners to get the sample weights, I can think of some workarounds, but otherwise I don't see a simple patch except copying the `StackingClassifier.fit` logic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I also recently realized that stacking estimators can't handle sample-weighted Pipelines. I addressed the issue by subclassing the `StackingRegressor` and `StackingClassifier` classes from scikit-learn and overwriting its `fit()` method to better manage Pipelines. Take a look at the following:

```
"""Implement StackingClassifier that can handle sample-weighted Pipelines."""

from sklearn.ensemble import StackingRegressor, StackingClassifier
from copy import deepcopy

import numpy as np
from joblib import Parallel

from sklearn.base import clone
from sklearn.base import is_classifier, is_regressor

from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_predict
from sklearn.model_selection import check_cv

from sklearn.utils import Bunch
from sklearn.utils.fixes import delayed

from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline

ESTIMATOR_NAME_IN_PIPELINE = 'estimator'

def new_fit_single_estimator(estimator, X, y, sample_weight=None,
                             message_clsname=None, message=None):
    """Private function used to fit an estimator within a job."""
    if sample_weight is not None:
        try:
            if isinstance(estimator, Pipeline):
                # determine name of final estimator
                estimator_name = estimator.steps[-1][0]
                kwargs = {estimator_name + '__sample_weight': sample_weight}
                estimator.fit(X, y, **kwargs)
            else:
                estimator.fit(X, y, sample_weight=sample_weight)
        except TypeError as exc:
            if "unexpected keyword argument 'sample_weight'" in str(exc):
                raise TypeError(
                    "Underlying estimator {} does not support sample weights."
                    .format(estimator.__class__.__name__)
                ) from exc
            raise
    else:
        estimator.fit(X, y)
    return estimator


class FlexibleStackingClassifier(StackingClassifier):

    def __init__(self, estimators, final_estimator=None, *, cv=None,
                 n_jobs=None, passthrough=False, verbose=0):
        super().__init__(
            estimators=estimators,
            final_estimator=final_estimator,
            cv=cv,
            n_jobs=n_jobs,
            passthrough=passthrough,
            verbose=verbose
        )

    def fit(self, X, y, sample_weight=None):
        """Fit the estimators.

        Parameters
        ----------
        X : {array-like, sparse matrix} of shape (n_samples, n_features)
            Training vectors, where `n_samples` is the number of samples and
            `n_features` is the number of features.
        y : array-like of shape (n_samples,)
            Target values.
        sample_weight : array-like of shape (n_samples,) or default=None
            Sample weights. If None, then samples are equally weighted.
            Note that this is supported only if all underlying estimators
            support sample weights.
            .. versionchanged:: 0.23
               when not None, `sample_weight` is passed to all underlying
               estimators

        Returns
        -------
        self : object
        """
        # all_estimators contains all estimators, the one to be fitted and the
        # 'drop' string.
        names, all_estimators = self._validate_estimators()
        self._validate_final_estimator()

        stack_method = [self.stack_method] * len(all_estimators)

        # Fit the base estimators on the whole training data. Those
        # base estimators will be used in transform, predict, and
        # predict_proba. They are exposed publicly.
        self.estimators_ = Parallel(n_jobs=self.n_jobs)(
            delayed(new_fit_single_estimator)(clone(est), X, y, sample_weight)
            for est in all_estimators if est != 'drop'
        )

        self.named_estimators_ = Bunch()
        est_fitted_idx = 0
        for name_est, org_est in zip(names, all_estimators):
            if org_est != 'drop':
                self.named_estimators_[name_est] = self.estimators_[
                    est_fitted_idx]
                est_fitted_idx += 1
            else:
                self.named_estimators_[name_est] = 'drop'

        # To train the meta-classifier using the most data as possible, we use
        # a cross-validation to obtain the output of the stacked estimators.

        # To ensure that the data provided to each estimator are the same, we
        # need to set the random state of the cv if there is one and we need to
        # take a copy.
        cv = check_cv(self.cv, y=y, classifier=is_classifier(self))
        if hasattr(cv, 'random_state') and cv.random_state is None:
            cv.random_state = np.random.RandomState()

        self.stack_method_ = [
            self._method_name(name, est, meth)
            for name, est, meth in zip(names, all_estimators, stack_method)
        ]
        fit_params = ({f"{ESTIMATOR_NAME_IN_PIPELINE}__sample_weight": sample_weight}
                      if sample_weight is not None
                      else None)
        predictions = Parallel(n_jobs=self.n_jobs)(
            delayed(cross_val_predict)(clone(est), X, y, cv=deepcopy(cv),
                                       method=meth, n_jobs=self.n_jobs,
                                       fit_params=fit_params,
                                       verbose=self.verbose)
            for est, meth in zip(all_estimators, self.stack_method_)
            if est != 'drop'
        )

        # Only not None or not 'drop' estimators will be used in transform.
        # Remove the None from the method as well.
        self.stack_method_ = [
            meth for (meth, est) in zip(self.stack_method_, all_estimators)
            if est != 'drop'
        ]

        X_meta = self._concatenate_predictions(X, predictions)
        new_fit_single_estimator(self.final_estimator_, X_meta, y,
                                 sample_weight=sample_weight)

        return self


class FlexibleStackingRegressor(StackingRegressor):

    def __init__(self, estimators, final_estimator=None, *, cv=None,
                 n_jobs=None, passthrough=False, verbose=0):
        super().__init__(
            estimators=estimators,
            final_estimator=final_estimator,
            cv=cv,
            n_jobs=n_jobs,
            passthrough=passthrough,
            verbose=verbose
        )

    def fit(self, X, y, sample_weight=None):
        """Fit the estimators.

        Parameters
        ----------
        X : {array-like, sparse matrix} of shape (n_samples, n_features)
            Training vectors, where `n_samples` is the number of samples and
            `n_features` is the number of features.
        y : array-like of shape (n_samples,)
            Target values.
        sample_weight : array-like of shape (n_samples,) or default=None
            Sample weights. If None, then samples are equally weighted.
            Note that this is supported only if all underlying estimators
            support sample weights.
            .. versionchanged:: 0.23
               when not None, `sample_weight` is passed to all underlying
               estimators

        Returns
        -------
        self : object
        """
        # all_estimators contains all estimators, the one to be fitted and the
        # 'drop' string.
        names, all_estimators = self._validate_estimators()
        self._validate_final_estimator()

        stack_method = [self.stack_method] * len(all_estimators)

        # Fit the base estimators on the whole training data. Those
        # base estimators will be used in transform, predict, and
        # predict_proba. They are exposed publicly.
        self.estimators_ = Parallel(n_jobs=self.n_jobs)(
            delayed(new_fit_single_estimator)(clone(est), X, y, sample_weight)
            for est in all_estimators if est != 'drop'
        )

        self.named_estimators_ = Bunch()
        est_fitted_idx = 0
        for name_est, org_est in zip(names, all_estimators):
            if org_est != 'drop':
                self.named_estimators_[name_est] = self.estimators_[
                    est_fitted_idx]
                est_fitted_idx += 1
            else:
                self.named_estimators_[name_est] = 'drop'

        # To train the meta-classifier using the most data as possible, we use
        # a cross-validation to obtain the output of the stacked estimators.

        # To ensure that the data provided to each estimator are the same, we
        # need to set the random state of the cv if there is one and we need to
        # take a copy.
        cv = check_cv(self.cv, y=y, classifier=is_classifier(self))
        if hasattr(cv, 'random_state') and cv.random_state is None:
            cv.random_state = np.random.RandomState()

        self.stack_method_ = [
            self._method_name(name, est, meth)
            for name, est, meth in zip(names, all_estimators, stack_method)
        ]
        fit_params = ({f"{ESTIMATOR_NAME_IN_PIPELINE}__sample_weight": sample_weight}
                      if sample_weight is not None
                      else None)
        predictions = Parallel(n_jobs=self.n_jobs)(
            delayed(cross_val_predict)(clone(est), X, y, cv=deepcopy(cv),
                                       method=meth, n_jobs=self.n_jobs,
                                       fit_params=fit_params,
                                       verbose=self.verbose)
            for est, meth in zip(all_estimators, self.stack_method_)
            if est != 'drop'
        )

        # Only not None or not 'drop' estimators will be used in transform.
        # Remove the None from the method as well.
        self.stack_method_ = [
            meth for (meth, est) in zip(self.stack_method_, all_estimators)
            if est != 'drop'
        ]

        X_meta = self._concatenate_predictions(X, predictions)
        new_fit_single_estimator(self.final_estimator_, X_meta, y,
                                 sample_weight=sample_weight)

        return self
```

I included both the Regressor and Classifier versions, though you only seem to need to be able to use the Classifier subclass.

**But a word of warning:** you must give your estimators the same name in your pipelines, and that name must align with the `ESTIMATOR_NAME_IN_PIPELINE` field defined below. Otherwise the code won't work. For example, here would be an appropriately defined `Pipeline` instance using the same name as defined in the class definition script shown above:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.linear_model import TweedieRegressor
from sklearn.feature_selection import VarianceThreshold

validly_named_pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('variance_threshold', VarianceThreshold()),
    ('scaler', StandardScaler()),
    ('estimator', TweedieRegressor())
])
```

This isn't ideal, but it's what I have for now and should work regardless.

**Edit:** Just to be clear, when I was overwriting the `fit()` method I just copied and pasted the code from the scikit repository and made the necessary changes, which constituted only a few lines. So much of the pasted code is not my original work, but that of the scikit developers.

Comment: Very nice! Thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

For your case, since you have a nested pipeline, here are the keys you will have to use while passing parameters.

```
list(stack_pipe.get_params().keys())

['memory',
 'steps',
 'verbose',
 'stackingclassifier',
 'stackingclassifier__cv',
 'stackingclassifier__estimators',
 'stackingclassifier__final_estimator__objective',
 'stackingclassifier__final_estimator__use_label_encoder',
 'stackingclassifier__final_estimator__base_score',
 'stackingclassifier__final_estimator__booster',
 'stackingclassifier__final_estimator__colsample_bylevel',
 'stackingclassifier__final_estimator__colsample_bynode',
 'stackingclassifier__final_estimator__colsample_bytree',
 'stackingclassifier__final_estimator__gamma',
 'stackingclassifier__final_estimator__gpu_id',
 'stackingclassifier__final_estimator__importance_type',
 'stackingclassifier__final_estimator__interaction_constraints',
 'stackingclassifier__final_estimator__learning_rate',
 'stackingclassifier__final_estimator__max_delta_step',
 'stackingclassifier__final_estimator__max_depth',
 'stackingclassifier__final_estimator__min_child_weight',
 'stackingclassifier__final_estimator__missing',
 'stackingclassifier__final_estimator__monotone_constraints',
 'stackingclassifier__final_estimator__n_estimators',
 'stackingclassifier__final_estimator__n_jobs',
 'stackingclassifier__final_estimator__num_parallel_tree',
 'stackingclassifier__final_estimator__random_state',
 'stackingclassifier__final_estimator__reg_alpha',
 'stackingclassifier__final_estimator__reg_lambda',
 'stackingclassifier__final_estimator__scale_pos_weight',
 'stackingclassifier__final_estimator__subsample',
 'stackingclassifier__final_estimator__tree_method',
 'stackingclassifier__final_estimator__validate_parameters',
 'stackingclassifier__final_estimator__verbosity',
 'stackingclassifier__final_estimator',
 'stackingclassifier__n_jobs',
 'stackingclassifier__passthrough',
 'stackingclassifier__stack_method',
 'stackingclassifier__verbose',
 'stackingclassifier__lr',
 'stackingclassifier__lr__memory',
 'stackingclassifier__lr__steps',
 'stackingclassifier__lr__verbose',
 'stackingclassifier__lr__standardscaler',
 'stackingclassifier__lr__logisticregression',
 'stackingclassifier__lr__standardscaler__copy',
 'stackingclassifier__lr__standardscaler__with_mean',
 'stackingclassifier__lr__standardscaler__with_std',
 'stackingclassifier__lr__logisticregression__C',
 'stackingclassifier__lr__logisticregression__class_weight',
 'stackingclassifier__lr__logisticregression__dual',
 'stackingclassifier__lr__logisticregression__fit_intercept',
 'stackingclassifier__lr__logisticregression__intercept_scaling',
 'stackingclassifier__lr__logisticregression__l1_ratio',
 'stackingclassifier__lr__logisticregression__max_iter',
 'stackingclassifier__lr__logisticregression__multi_class',
 'stackingclassifier__lr__logisticregression__n_jobs',
 'stackingclassifier__lr__logisticregression__penalty',
 'stackingclassifier__lr__logisticregression__random_state',
 'stackingclassifier__lr__logisticregression__solver',
 'stackingclassifier__lr__logisticregression__tol',
 'stackingclassifier__lr__logisticregression__verbose',
 'stackingclassifier__lr__logisticregression__warm_start']
```

If you look closely, there is no `sample_weight` key present in the `final_estimator`. You may want to check the original API to see if this is depreciated or renamed.

Comment: `sample_weight` is a fitting parameter (data-dependent), not an "attribute" parameter, so you wouldn't expect to see it in `get_params()`.